# Применение паттерна Модуль JS

Tags: javascript, шаблоны-проектирования

Хотелось бы узнать побольше о методах применения паттерна Модуль, если можно на реальных примерах. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Паттерн модуль нужен для реализации инкапсуляции данных в JS и для предотвращения засорения глобальной области видимости. Например есть книга "Javascript Шаблоны", там есть полное описание и примеры этого паттерна, и много других интересных вещей.

Примеры:

1. Тут мы предотвращаем засорение глобальной области видимости, обернув наш код в модуль:

   ```
   (function(){
      var x = 20;
      // какой-то код, использующий Х
   }())

   console.log(x) // Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined, тут x не доступен
   ```
2. Реализация инкапсуляции. Делаем глобальный объект с публичным интерфейсом и приватными данными. В данном случае пример бессмысленный, но на этой основе можно делать много полезных вещей.

   ```
   var Lib = (function(){
       // Приватные данные, недоступные извне
       var __Pi = 3.14;

       // Публичный интерфейс, доступный извне, использующий приватные данные
       return {
           calcCircleArea: function(r) {
               return __Pi * Math.pow(r,2);
           },
           calcCircleCircumference: function(r) {
               return 2 * __Pi * r;
           }
       }
   }())

   Lib.calcCircleArea(10) // узнать площадь круга радиусом 10
   Lib.calcCircleCircumference(10) // узнать длина окружности круга радиусом 10
   ```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.